# What sub-format of Word document does Pages use for export?

Tags: macos, ms-office, pages, iwork

I am using Pages '09 (v 4.3) and LibreOffice under OSX. When exporting a document from Pages into Word format, I am unable to open it in LibreOffice. (I would swear I had done this successfully many times before.) I think LibreOffice doesn't know which of the many Word formats to use. It shows me these specific options in the Open dialog:

[image: dialog screengrab]

I was assuming it was not the most current because the extension is `.doc` instead of `.docx` but I tried changing the ext and it still fails to open correctly.

Any tips on which of the formats to select or how to get my document to open in LibreOffice? (I need to do "compare two documents".)

Comment: The New version of Pages  v5.Give you the Advance Option to Export as .docx or .doc (Word 1997 -2003 Compatible)

Answer (score 2):

I just tried this out – The following happened.

WRONGE way:
Open a new document in Pages, File -> Export To (Word..) -> Advanced Options -> Choose .docx format.
LibreOffice crashes everytime I try to open the file.

RIGHT way:
Open a new document in Pages, File -> Export To (Word..) -> Advanced Options -> Choose **.doc** format.
Then it opens fine in LibreOffice.

NOTE: This was tested in Pages version 5.0

PS: Didnt see the post before me. Sorry about that.

PPS: It seems you are trying to open a specific format, but the problem is really the way you export it in the first place. Please write if you can't export in .doc format.